# How to disable flickering of scroll bar when constantly changing multiline text box content?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, scroll

So I'm using this code which moves the cursor to the end of the text box content each time I'm adding something to it.

```
void txtDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDisplay.SelectionStart = txtDisplay.Text.Length;
    txtDisplay.ScrollToCaret();
    txtDisplay.Refresh();
}
```

The problem is that I see like flickering of text box scroll bar which goes up and down each time I add something to the text box. Doing this 10 times a second seems like it consumes some processing power and it looks ugly.

How to keep the scroll bar scrolled down all the time?

Comment: Be sure you use AppendText() instead of assigning the Text property.

Comment: You are asking a lot from your end users to try to keep up with a text box that is getting updates 10 times a second.  Try buffering some of these "updates" into a variable, then update the text box with the variable at a more reasonable rate.

Comment: @LarsTech, this is a good idea. I haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there ( again :) ),

I've just looked for some methods to avoid this flickering and I found [this post](http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2005/08/15/2092.aspx) exploring both `SelectedText` property and `AppendText()` method, with the lattest actually appending the text and scrolling *only* if it's necessary.

Hope that'll help !

Comment: Nice. I have tried this earlier but I had it formatted incorrectly, and article pointed out how could this be done. Thanks.